# How to access the internal properties of one assembly from another assembly without using InternalVisibleTo?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Without using the signing key (.snk) is there a way to access the internal property of one assembly from another assembly ?

Thanks in advance.
Arun

Comment: Using reflection?

Comment: Yes it should be efficient

Comment: The reflection can be backed into a strongly typed delegate... Its speed should be similar to a `virtual` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reflection when used through strongly typed delegates isn't TOO much slow... (it should be just a little slower than `virtual` method calls):

Example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    internal int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
public static class MyClassAccessor
{
    public static readonly Func<MyClass, int> GetMyProperty;
    public static readonly Action<MyClass, int> SetMyProperty;

    static MyClassAccessor()
    {
        var prop = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("MyProperty", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        GetMyProperty = (Func<MyClass, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<MyClass, int>), prop.GetMethod);
        SetMyProperty = (Action<MyClass, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<MyClass, int>), prop.SetMethod);
    }
}
```

And you use like:

```
var mc = new MyClass();
MyClassAccessor.SetMyProperty(mc, 5);
Console.WriteLine(MyClassAccessor.GetMyProperty(mc));
```